# Is my luggage automatically transferred from Jeju Air to Air India at Incheon airport?

Tags: transit, luggage, air-india, jeju

I am traveling on Jeju Air to Seoul and then connecting to Air India. Will my checked in luggage be automatically transferred to the Air India flight or do I have to do it myself?

Comment: Single ticket ? And Jeju isn't a member of Star Alliance, so in most probability I think no. But better confirm with the airline.

Comment: @DumbCoder I booked through GotoGate. I think the Booking ID which I have with GotoGate is same for both, whereas the airline PNR is different.